# ¿Como calcular tiempo trascurrido entre dos horas js?

Tags: javascript

quiero calcular el tiempo trascurrido entre dos horas explico:
tengo un formulario para la fabricación de alimentos, pero este tiene un campo llamado turno el cual dependiendo de la hora indica si es turno|| 1 = 5 --2 || 2 =14 -- 22 ||3= 22---5 del siguiente día siguiendo un ejemplo pude calcular las horas trascurrida el problema es cuando llega el cambio de día ej.: inician fabricación a las 22 y terminan a la 1 del siguiente día aquí el problema en resumen quiero que me calcule el tiempo trascurrido entre dos horas teniendo en cuenta el día

gracias de antemano

**js**

```js
  var minutos_inicio = hora_inicio.split(':')
    .reduce((p, c) => parseInt(p) * 60 + parseInt(c));
  var minutos_final = hora_final.split(':')
    .reduce((p, c) => parseInt(p) * 60 + parseInt(c));
  
 
  if (minutos_final < minutos_inicio) return;
  
 
  var diferencia = minutos_final - minutos_inicio;
  
 
  var horas = Math.floor(diferencia / 60);
  var minutos = diferencia % 60;
  
  $('#horas_real').val(horas + ':'
    + (minutos < 10 ? '0' : '') + minutos);  
}

$('#hora_inicio').change(calculardiferencia);
$('#hora_final').change(calculardiferencia);
calculardiferencia();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="time" id="hora_inicio" value="" />
<input type="time" id="hora_hasta" value="" />
<input type="text" id="horas_real" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una buena opción puede ser encapsular un objeto `Date` y trabajar encima en vez de transformar los números.
Además de que si quieres considerar el tiempo entre `22:30` horas y `03:23` no puedes arreglarlo fácilmente por la línea:

```
if (minutos_final < minutos_inicio) return;
```

Claro que luego podrían anidar un `if` o un `else` pero el código empieza a dejar de ser tan intuitivo.

Nota: `36e5` es la notación científica de `60 * 60 * 1000`, i.e. `36*10^5` que son la cantidad de milisegundos en una hora, lo mismo para `6e4 = 60 * 1000`

```js
const inicio = document.getElementById('inicio'),
    final = document.getElementById('final'),
    resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');

// en formato 24 hrs, ejemplo: '12:30', '03:47', '19:12'
function horaFija(hora) {
    const dia = new Date()
    dia.setHours(...hora.split(':'), 0)
    return dia
}

function calculaIntervalo(horaInicio, horaFinal) {
    let fechaInicio = horaFija(horaInicio),
        fechaFinal = horaFija(horaFinal)

    if (fechaFinal < fechaInicio) {
        fechaFinal.setDate(fechaFinal.getDate() + 1)
    }

    const diferencia = fechaFinal - fechaInicio,
        horas = Math.floor(diferencia / 36e5),
        minutos = Math.floor((diferencia % 36e5) / 6e4)
    return [horas, minutos]
}

inicio.addEventListener('change', e => resultado.value = calculaIntervalo(e.target.value, final.value))
final.addEventListener('change', e => resultado.value = calculaIntervalo(inicio.value, e.target.value))
```

```html
<input type="time" id="inicio" value="12:40">
<input type="time" id="final" value="06:45">
<input id="resultado">
```

---

Si quisieras definir tus intervalos e identificarlos fácilmente podrías agrupar varias funciones en un array y ver en cual indice esta:

```
const turnos = [
    hora => horaFija('05:00') <= hora && hora < horaFija('14:00'),
    hora => horaFija('14:00') <= hora && hora < horaFija('22:00'),
    hora => horaFija('22:00') <= hora || hora < horaFija('05:00')
]

// regresa 0
turnos.findIndex( turno => turno( horaFija('7:20') ) )

// regresa 1
turnos.findIndex( turno => turno( horaFija('15:12') ) )

// regresan 2
turnos.findIndex( turno => turno( horaFija('22:54') ) )
turnos.findIndex( turno => turno( horaFija('02:03') ) )

// regresa -1 en caso de que algo fallé y no cumpla nada
turnos.findIndex(t => t('foo'))
```

Esto te permite mucha flexibilidad en cuanto a la cantidad de intervalos que puedes tener y en que distribuciones los necesitas.

Es conveniente hacer un preprocesamiento en el evento `'onchange'` para ver en que intervalo están las horas y listo.

Comment: Estoy utilizando este código para un pequeño proyecto, sería posible devolver en el campo **id="horas_real"** un formato 00:00:00 en este momento devuelve un formato **0,0**