# Problema con Autoselect dependiendo de input Onchange JS

Tags: javascript, html, select, datetime

tengo este formulario:

```
    const inicio = document.getElementById('id_time'),
    final = document.getElementById('id_notificacion_date'),
    resultado = document.getElementById('id_sla');

// en formato 24 hrs, ejemplo: '12:30', '03:47', '19:12'
function horaFija(hora) {
    const dia = new Date()
    dia.setHours(...hora.split(':'), 0)
    return dia
}

function calculaIntervalo(horaInicio, horaFinal) {
    let fechaInicio = horaFija(horaInicio),
        fechaFinal = horaFija(horaFinal)

    if (fechaFinal < fechaInicio) {
        fechaFinal.setDate(fechaFinal.getDate() + 1)
    }

    const diferencia = fechaFinal - fechaInicio,
        horas = Math.floor(diferencia / 36e5),
        minutos = Math.floor((diferencia % 36e5) / 6e4)
    return (horas <= 9 ? "0" : "") + horas + ":" + (minutos <= 9 ? "0" : "") + minutos;
}

inicio.addEventListener('change', e => resultado.value = calculaIntervalo(e.target.value, final.value))
final.addEventListener('change', e => resultado.value = calculaIntervalo(inicio.value, e.target.value))
```

```
<input type="time" id="id_time" value="00:00">
<input type="time" id="id_notificacion_date" value="00:00">
<input id="id_sla">
```

Tomado de [¿Como calcular tiempo trascurrido entre dos horas js?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/451956/como-calcular-tiempo-trascurrido-entre-dos-horas-js)

Pero quiero agregar otro input tipo SELCT

```
<select name="status_sla" id="id_status_sla">
    <option value="1">A TIEMPO</option>
    <option value="2">FUERA DE SLA</option>
</select>
```

que si el valor de `<input id="id_sla">` es mayor a 15 Minutos (00:15) el Select automáticamente seleccione "FUERA DE SLA" y si es igual o menor "A TIEMPO"

Espero me puedan ayudar de antemano muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al HTML le agregue otro option con la propiedad "selected" que seria la opcion por defecto

```
<select name="status_sla" id="id_status_sla">
    <option value="1">A TIEMPO</option>
    <option value="2">FUERA DE SLA</option>
    <option value="3" selected>NO DEFINIDO</option>
</select>
```

y agrego dos funciones que realizan el cambio (al tener horas=0 y minutos<=15) en el select a la opción "FUERA DE SLA, y si esa condición no se cumple la opción seleccionada será "A TIEMPO":

```
 function changeStatusWithStart(event){
    resultado.value = calculaIntervalo(event.target.value, final.value)
    if(resultado.value.slice(0,2)==0 && resultado.value.slice(3,5) <= 15) estado.value = "1";
    else estado.value = "2"
}

function changeStatusWithEnd(event){
    resultado.value = calculaIntervalo(inicio.value, event.target.value)
    if(resultado.value.slice(0,2)==0 && resultado.value.slice(3,5) <= 15) estado.value = "1";
    else estado.value = "2"
}
```

Estas funciones se disparan salir del focus de cualquiera de los 2 inputs inicio y final (es parte de lo que hace el evento change) y asigno una funcion para el input="inicio" y otra para el input="final"

```
inicio.addEventListener('change', e => changeStatusWithStart(e))
final.addEventListener('change', e => changeStatusWithEnd(e))
```

Se podria realizar con una funcion seguramente y usar la misma funcion con los 2 eventos pero eso te lo dejo a vos. Saludos.